# What is the best time complexity data structure for finding max value in an array?

Tags: tree, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

Instead of traversing through the whole array which takes O(n) time, what is the best data structure for finding the max value? E.g. a binary search tree has O(log n) average case but O(n) worst case. Is there one with O(log n) worst case?

Comment: This question needs to be clarified. If *find* time is the only constraint, you could simply keep your array sorted by shifting the burden to the insert operation, inserting objects in the correct position. Relatedly, you could use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Comment: do you mean a max heap?

Comment: yes a binary heap would be O(1) for find max right?

Comment: @Naomi Yes indeed so

Answer (score 0):

Given an unknown array, it is impossible to find the maximum in less than `O(n)` time, just because you cannot conclude until you have seen all `n` values. Whatever the order of your accesses, the maximum can always be the last.

Transferring the values to a data structure such as a binary search tree or a heap will not help, on the opposite.

Comment: Why will it not help? The max value will always be on top of the max heap right?

Comment: @Naomi: It takes `O(n)` to build the heap. You can't beat `O(n)`.